# Check routing in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-routing

I want to learn symfony and I start to create a small application. I have a question related to the routes. So, I have in my project the routes :

`/admin/homepage`, `/admin/news`, `admin/galery`

No if I write in url `/admin`, this route doesn't exist and I get as error `No route found for "GET /admin/"`. Exist a way to check if route doesn't exist and redirect to another route for example ? Thx in advance and sorry for my english 
My routes :

```
news_all:
path: /news/all/{page}
defaults: { _controller: AppAdminBundle:News:all, page: 1 }
requirements:
    page: \d+
    _method:  GET|POST
news_add:
path: /news/add
defaults: { _controller: AppAdminBundle:News:add }
```

Comment: You can add `indexAction` and add redirect to desired function in that.

Comment: how did you define the routes in the controller?

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

In your case the best solution would be to override default `ExceptionController` and add custom logic there, e.g. redirection to other page - according to the docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html#overriding-the-default-exceptioncontroller

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    exception_controller:  AppBundle:Exception:showException
```

*Note:*
Instead of creating a new exception controller from scratch you can, of course, also extend the default `ExceptionController`. In that case, you might want to override one or both of the `showAction()` and `findTemplate()` methods. The latter one locates the template to be used.

Comment: sorry  but I don't understand how the redirect will be maked if I will accees a non exist route

Comment: When you access route that does not exists, `HttpNotFoundException` is fired, than that exception is catched by `Symfony2` exception listener and `ExceptionConttroller` will be called. All you have to do is to implement your custom `ExceptionController` and redirect user to proper route with simple `$this->redirectToToute('your_route')` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony's good practise are to set rout in your controller, using annotations

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
```

and

```
/**
* @Route("/news/add", name="news_add")
*/
public function addAction()
{
    // ...
}
```

Also, with annotation, you can set rout for a whole controller.
Which is, in your case, what you're looking for.

```
/**
* @Route("/admin")
*/
class NewsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/news/add", name="news_add")
     */
    public function addAction()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Also, I advice you to take a look at [@Template annotation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/view.html).

Else, to answer your question, I think you  can make a custom twig function (check [this link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) for more information). Function that checks is the given name a valid route:

```
function routeExists($name)
{
    // I assume that you have a link to the container in your twig extension class
    $router = $this->container->get('router');
    return (null === $router->getRouteCollection()->get($name)) ? false : true;
}
```

Comment: Can you please help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39715888/symfony-2-router-with-parameter-returns-404/